# Permission denied while starting the Hbase in cluster mode with 3 nodes

Tags: hbase

I have three systems with hbase installed,

```
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-saichanda-master-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out
slave1: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-lakshman.out
slave1: /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 189: /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-lakshman.out: Permission denied
master: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out
slave2: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-hash1.out
slave2: /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 189: /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-hash1.out: Permission denied
slave1: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-lakshman.out' for reading: No such file or directory
slave2: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-saichanda-regionserver-hash1.out' for reading: No such file or directory
```

How to resolve this error?

I have three nodes with username saichanda, ip addresses, 10.0.3.18(master), 10.0.3.68(slave1), 10.0.3.70 (slave2) and the content of the 
hbase-site.xml is as follows: in (master)

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>master:60000</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:50000/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>master</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As which user you are starting the services? Check whether that user has permission to create log files in the directories mentioned in the logs.

Comment: @Subash Kunjupillai, I am starting the services as master, saichanda@10.0.3.18. As you have seen in the output, master logging is fine, but when comes to the creation of log files in the directories /usr/local/... So do I require to give sudo give permission to them? will it work if I start hbase with sudo.. I will check now, but do you have anything to say on this...

Comment: I found the error, permission was denied to create log files in the slave nodes' `/usr/local/hbase/logs` directory. So, it was saying permission denied. In the sense, when I did `ls -l` on the logs directory in slave machines, it did not have write permission, hence not able to create log file in slave machines from master node.. Now, I changed the permissions of the `/usr/local/hbase/logs` directory to writable, using, `chmod -R 777 /usr/.../logs` in both the slave, Now it starts working.. So is it safe to change permissions for the log files? Is there any other way of solving the same?